How to hook up a resize event for a canvas in Angular
I have an Angular component with a canvas, like so:
<div>
    <canvas #canvas [width]='displayCanvasWidth' [height]='displayCanvasHeight'>
    </canvas>
</div>

When I set the value of displayCanvasWidth in the component's .ts file the canvas changes size as expected.
How can I hook in to the resize event of the canvas?
In the .ts file I've set a variable for the canvas and that is working fine:
@ViewChild('canvas', { static: true })
private displayCanvas:ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | null = null;

Neither of the following is working for me:
this.displayCanvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('resize', this.OnDisplayCanvasSizeChanged, false);

or
this.displayCanvas.nativeElement.onresize = this.OnDisplayCanvasSizeChanged;

where the function is define like so:
public OnDisplayCanvasSizeChanged(e:any) {
    alert("Here!");
  }


Canvas do not fire resize event. You should call your method on @Input setter.

ok, thanks, In light of that I have posted another question that fully explains my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78677875/how-to-address-flickering-when-resizing-a-canvas-element-in-an-angular-app
