How to address flickering when resizing a canvas element in an Angular app
I have an Angular component with a canvas, like so:
<canvas #canvas [width]='displayCanvasWidth' [height]='displayCanvasHeight'></canvas>

In the .ts file I've set a variable to access canvas element and that is working fine. like so:
@ViewChild('canvas', { static: true })
private displayCanvas:ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> | null = null;

Now, I draw my scene and all is well. The scene animates smoothly with a timer and I also hook in to the mousemove event of the canvas to do some further mouse-position-dependent rendering, and it all is working fine.
I have been careful to draw my whole scene (which is made up of several canvases) on to a programmatically created off-screen canvas before using the drawImage method on my #canvas element to copy my finished off-screen canvas so that I only ever make one call the visible canvas when anything updates in the scene. This is all working fine.
When I set the value of displayCanvasWidth in the component's .ts file the canvas changes size as expected, but of course I need to redraw mu scene to allow for it's new size.
So, for testing, I add a button and on the click event of this button I call:
this.displayCanvasWidth = (this.displayCanvasWidth == 800 ? 801) : 800;

then I call my draw method to draw the scene, the one which only calls drawImage on the #canvas element and which is working fine when called many times during animation and on mousemove.
So now I can keep toggling the width of the canvas on each button click.
My problem is that I notice that changing the width of the canvas like this is causing a flickering. The canvas clears itself to white before I see the results of my draw method.
In fact, if I call my draw method immediately after setting the value of this.displayCanvasWidth then the canvas just stays white. I have to call my method using setTimeout with a 1 millisecond delay, and then my draw function works but with the flicker still there.
Would anyone know how I might solve this issue? Thanks.

Have you considered using scale transformation (transform) instead of changing the width ? You would get performance improvments because width implier layout rendering phase and transform implies layout painting phase. see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Critical_rendering_path

I worked extensively with canvas several years ago and encountered the same flickering issue. To solve this, I used two canvases: one visible and one in memory. I made all the changes on the off-screen canvas and only used the drawImage method to copy the result to the visible canvas.

Instead of trying to fix the flickering, try displaying an overlay to hide the flicker.
In ngOnChanges which triggers when you change the @Input to different values. you can display a overlay screen which has the content loading...
loading = false;
...

...
ngOnChanges() {
    this.loading = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.loading = false;
    }, 700);
}

The html will show the overlay
<div style="position: relative;">
    <canvas #canvas [width]='displayCanvasWidth' [height]='displayCanvasHeight'></canvas>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom: 0px; background-color: black; color: white;"> Loading... </div>
</div>


Thanks for your answer but in my case this is not what I need. For example, imagine that I am drawing a square which occupies 50% of the width of the canvas. When I resize the canvas I need to execute my draw code to draw the square again. This happens on each button press (or each resize of the canvas for whatever reason - maybe window resizing). I can't be putting up an overlay each time. I just want to redraw without flicking to white each time.

@gnitsuk please share working demo for everyone to check the code

Your comment caused me to try and recreate the issue in stackblitz, and that was interesting. It works fine with no flicking to white in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-equuvw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.html If I do not call ResetCanvas in the  click function then screen goes white as expected, same behavior as in my main app, However, in my main (Angular Electron) app if I do call RenderCanvas then AFTER it has painted blue (I breakpoint to see it) then canvas clears to white, hence me having to call again in 1 millisecond.

So, its like, resize change causes canvas to clear white then blue fill is called in stackblitz version, but in my  Election app the resize change is causing the white fill to occur AFTER my blue fill call, so that the last thing I see is a white canvas instead of a blue one.
